# How to end the do while loop on my demand?

Tags: c, fibonacci, do-while

The following code generates Fibonacci numbers using a Do While function, instead of specifying the exact number of the exit condition while (b < 144) I want to be less precise and just make it not to show numbers that are greater that an specific value (let's say 150). 
how can I do it?
please note that I'm only know basic functions.

```
        int main()
{
    int a;
    int b = 0;
    int c = 1;
    printf("the fibonacci numbers up to 144 are:\n");
    printf("%i", b);
    do
    {
        a = c+b;
        printf("\n%i", a);
        c = a+b;
        printf("\n%i", c);
        b = c+a;
        printf("\n%i", b);
    }
    while (b < 144);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `CTRL+C`, if you're on Linux.

Comment: `CTRL+D` on LINUX and `CTRL+Z` on WINNOWS.

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite understand what you want. "I want to be less precise and just make it not to show numbers that are greater that an specific value (let's say 150)"

Comment: Change the condition in the while loop. Do you know about `if` statements?

Comment: The loop ends when number 144 is reached, I want it to end on the same number but the condition to be "the biggest Fibonacci number up to 150 is:...").

Comment: Yep, I know if and else statements.

Comment: @user3142487 you should explain the question better. Change the condition in the while loop to what suits you.

Comment: Are you asking "how to replace 144 with 150"? Your title seem to be asking about "break" statement as marianoc84 suggested, but the body talks about changing condition...

Comment: What exactly do you want to generate?

Comment: I'll try to keep it simple: when it will be complete the program will ask the user for a value. there will be no Fibonacci numbers generated above that value.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what do you intend for *"on demand"*. If you mean *on demand by code* you could use an internal `if` and if condition is true then exit the loop with [break](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/pdthelp/v1r1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.debugtool.doc_7.1/eqa7rm0280.htm) command. Example extracted by linked URL:

```
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
   if (string[i] == '\0')
      break;
   length++;
}
```

If *on demand* means "as soon you want to stop it" then use `CTRL+C` sice you are in a console application.

**Edit:** Since your function already exit on command, you probably want to know *"how to read the standard input in a console application?"*
Answer: Using the scanf function (here an example):

```
#include <stdio.h>   

int main() {
    int n;
    printf("Insert the value of N: ");
    scanf ("%d",&n);
    printf("N*N is equal to: %d\n", n*n);
    getch();    
}
```

Comment: +1: "break" is indeed answer to title of the post... is it the question OP have in mind is still open question :)

Comment: Thanks! break helps, didn't know that it can be used with if statements.

Comment: Almost everything can be wrapped in a if statement. Even an if statement ;)

Comment: PS: there are smarter way to achieve what you want.

Comment: I would like to know please...

Comment: you should basically never use break statements in a loop, because it`s bad programming style! use a boolean variable, which you can set to false if you want to end the loop

Comment: That's one of the smarter way...

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use somthing like that :

```
while (a < MAX_VALUE && b < MAX_VALUE && c < MAX_VALUE)
```

Where MAX_VALUE is a preprocessor macro at the start of your program after the includes (http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Macros.html#Macros), for example :

```
#define MAX_VALUE 100000
```

Comment: It doesn't help, generates up to 610...

Comment: @user3142487 It's because MAX_VALUE is really big, you can set it to any value you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can enter the limit for the number up to which do you want the series.

```
int n;
printf("Enter the limit: ");
scanf("%d", &n);
printf("\nthe fibonacci numbers up to %d are:\n", n);
printf("%i", b);
do
{
   ...
   n--;
}
while (n);
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved it: added a user specified limit and an if statement to check after each addition:
thanks for the help!

```
float lim;
int a;
int b = 0;
int c = 1;
printf("The following program generates Fibonacci numbers up to a specified value\n");
printf("Please enter a value of your choise:");
scanf("%f4", &lim);
printf("the fibonacci numbers up to %.2f are:\n", lim);
printf("%i", b);
do
{
    a = c+b;
    c = a+b;
    b = c+a;
    if ( a >= lim) break;
    printf("\n%i", a);
    if ( c >= lim) break;
    printf("\n%i", c);
    if ( b >= lim) break;
    printf("\n%i", b);
}
while(b <= lim);
```